# Trigger causing application to become unresponsive

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, triggers, node-postgres

I have been having an issue with an unresponsive node application for a few days now. It started with when I added in a new trigger. The trigger runs on every new insert to a table, and the trigger function copies all rows older than one month over to an archive table. Typically we can have 10 or more records be inserted every ~5 seconds; I don't see that to be much of a load on the database. The node app uses the pg module.

I discovered when I enabled the trigger, the application would stop running. When I disabled it, a huge backlog of requests would flood the system and the app would start working normally again. This issue would only manifest itself after ~10-15 minutes of running time. I thought it wouldn't be an issue since most of the time there'd be nothing for the trigger to do, but obviously I'm missing something here. Does running a trigger on record insert impose that much of an overhead that it causes the database to come to a screeching halt?

Answer (score 0):

Use [pg_stat_statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/pgstatstatements.html) with `pg_stat_statements.track = all` to find out which query hogs your database.